# Compass delimited list separator - how to set to &#8211;

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using SASS/Compass to create a breadcrumb with the Compass mixin "`@include delimited-list();`"

I have a variable called `$breadcrumb-separator: " > ";` so that I can change the character out in different situations.

My css is: `ul.nav {@include delimited-list($breadcrumb-separator);}`

How can I change the use of the character ">", to use the en dash(`&#8211; or &ndash;`) entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this include generates a :after element, you need to use unicode hex escapes for your `&ndash;` and it should work as expected:

```
$breadcrumb-separator: " \2013 ";
```

Comment: Thanks Tino! I was using \u2013 and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.